# Not able to send mails using Office365 as SMTP server in Bugzilla 5.0

Tags: email, ubuntu, smtp, office365, bugzilla

I am looking for a solution to configure bugzilla to send out mails using office365 as smtpserver.

I have Bugzilla 5.0 hosted on Ubuntu14.0.4

I have also applied patch for SMTP::TLS mentioned here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8846930&action=edit

Updated section in Mailer.pm file as per above patch:-

```
if ($method eq "SMTP::TLS") {
    my ($host, $port) = split(/:/, Bugzilla->params->{'smtpserver'}, 2);
    $transport = Bugzilla->request_cache->{smtp} //=
      Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS->new({
        host  => $host,
        defined($port) ? (port => $port) : (),
        sasl_username => Bugzilla->params->{'smtp_username'},
        sasl_password => Bugzilla->params->{'smtp_password'},
        helo => $hostname,
        #ssl => Bugzilla->params->{'smtp_ssl'},
        ssl => 'starttls',
        debug => Bugzilla->params->{'smtp_debug'} });
}
```

**Config in params.json:**

```
"mail_delivery_method" : "SMTP::TLS",
"smtp_ssl" : "1",
"smtp_username" : "user.name@domain.com",
"smtpserver" : "smtp.office365.com:587",
"smtppassword" : "<mypassword>"
```

**Error:**

There was an error sending mail ....... failed AUTH: Command unknown: 'AUTH'

**Traceback:**

at Bugzilla/Mailer.pm line 194.

```
Bugzilla::Mailer::MessageToMTA(...) called at Bugzilla/BugMail.pm line 381

Bugzilla::BugMail::sendMail(...) called at Bugzilla/BugMail.pm line 280

Bugzilla::BugMail::Send(...) called at Bugzilla/Bug.pm line 1355

Bugzilla::Bug::_send_bugmail(...) called at Bugzilla/Bug.pm line 1293

Bugzilla::Bug::send_changes(...) called at /var/www/html/bugzilla/process_bug.cgi line 386
```

**Software error:**

Can't locate object method "disconnect" via package "Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS" at Bugzilla.pm line 686.
END failed--call queue aborted at /var/www/html/bugzilla/process_bug.cgi line 150.

For help, please send mail to the webmaster (webmaster@localhost), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

Am I missing some config here or this is an issue?